# why it says that there is no line in the clients InputStream?(socket programming)

Tags: java, sockets

I tried to write a simple program that runs a server and then accepts two clients. Then one of them tries to send a string to another client.
but my code doesn't work and I don't know why.

This is my TestClient class:

```
public class TestClient extends Thread{

int id;
String Name;
Socket client;
boolean isAsk;


public TestClient(int id,String clientName,boolean isAsk) throws IOException {
    this.id=id;
    this.Name=clientName;
    this.isAsk=isAsk;
}


public void connectTheClientToTheLocalHost(ServerSocket server){
    try {
        client = new Socket("localhost",1111);
        server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readFromTerminal(){
    try {
        InputStream is=client.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
        pw.println("sdklfsdklfk");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void closeTheCientSocket(){
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void write(){
    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("file1.txt")));

        String st =sc.nextLine();

        bw.write(st);

        bw.close();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    if(isAsk){

        readFromTerminal();
    }
    else{

        write();
    }
}
```

and this is the main function:

```
public class PCServer {


public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(1111);
        TestClient t1=(new TestClient(1,"reza",true));
        TestClient t2=(new TestClient(2,"man",false));
        t1.connectTheClientToTheLocalHost(s);

        t1.start();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(t1.client.getInputStream());
        String st=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(st);
        t1.closeTheCientSocket();

        t2.connectTheClientToTheLocalHost(s);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(t2.client.getOutputStream());
        pw.println(st);
        pw.flush();

        t2.start();
        t2.closeTheCientSocket();


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

actually this code returns an exception in

```
String st=sc.nextLine();
```

in main function and says that there is no line found.
what is the problem?

Comment: What is the exception that it throws?

Comment: No such element exception:no line found

Answer (score 0):

ServerSocket in java usually used in another way.

If you need point-to-point connection, one host creates a ServerSocket and accepts connections. Examples:

**First host example:**

```
try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    // it more convenient to use DataInputStream instead of Scanner I think
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());) {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        String msg = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println("got request: " + msg);

        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1-response");
        dataOutputStream.flush();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Second host example:**

```
try(Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("2-request");
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        String msg = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println("got response: " + msg);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want one host talk to another over the server (broker), then you need plane java Sockets on hosts and ServerSocket on broker, and broker must transmit messages it received from one host to another. Examples:

**Broker** (run it in separate thread or process)

```
try {
    List<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<>();

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);

    // accepting connections from 2 clients
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        sockets.add(socket);
    }

    // streams for first host
    InputStream hostOneInputStream = sockets.get(0).getInputStream();
    DataInputStream hostOneDataInputStream = new DataInputStream(sockets.get(0).getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream hostOneDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(sockets.get(0).getOutputStream());

    // streams for second host
    InputStream hostTwoInputStream = sockets.get(1).getInputStream();
    DataInputStream hostTwoDataInputStream = new DataInputStream(sockets.get(1).getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream hostTwoDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(sockets.get(1).getOutputStream());

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        if (hostOneInputStream.available() > 0) {
            String msg = hostOneDataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("got message from host 1: " + msg);

            hostTwoDataOutputStream.writeUTF(msg);
            hostTwoDataOutputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("message " + msg + " sent to host two");
        }

        if (hostTwoInputStream.available() > 0) {
            String msg = hostTwoDataInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("got message from host 2: " + msg);

            hostOneDataOutputStream.writeUTF(msg);
            hostOneDataOutputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("message " + msg + " sent to host one");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**First host** (run it in separate thread or process)

```
try(Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1");
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        String msg = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println("got msg: " + msg);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Second host** (run it in separate thread or process)

```
try(Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        String msg = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println("got msg: " + msg);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("2");
        dataOutputStream.flush();
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually I want to write a program that runs a server and lets clients to interact with each other through the server.

Comment: @user109107 so the example with broker is that what you're looking for. clients will interact with each other through the broker (server)

Comment: But what's wrong with my code? I think my code is somehow like that example with broker except that my code do the job with different methods